# Why as_json does not return empty object in has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one

I've `user` and `address`.
One user has one address. so I use applied following association.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and in controller:

```
render json: User.find(1).as_json(include: :address)
```

The problem is:

it returns a JSON object like

```
{id: 1, name: "abc", address: {id: 1, user_id: 1}}
```

if I have an address for user id 1.

but I don't have an address of any user. it returns

```
{id: 1, name: "abc"}
```

but I want response like

```
{id: 1, name: "abc", address: {}}
```

if user don't have address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more rails-ey way of doing it, but you can just redefine the `address` attribute:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ...
  ...

  def address
    super || {}
  end
end
```

When the serializer checks the address, if it's present it will return the address, and if it's nil or false, it will return an empty hash instead of not appearing.

EDIT: As per the comment, this needs to go in the UserSerializer and not the User model, edited code above

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I got an error `undefined method serializable_hash' for {}:Hash`

Comment: Ahh sorry I think you need it in the serializer, I'll edit

Comment: @JasjeetSingh What mark is saying here you need to have https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers installed in your project. And then generate a UserSerializer and place the code as mention above